# libuuid not linking in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, ubuntu, lib

The above problem is not resolved in ubuntu 16.04 . 
I tried it but still not working . here are the results of steps I followed :

> ~$ apt-cache search libuuid
>
> libuuid-perl - Perl extension for using UUID interfaces as defined in e2fsprogs libuuid1 - Universally Unique ID library uuid-dev - Universally Unique ID library - headers and static libraries uuid-runtime - runtime components for the Universally Unique ID library libdata-uuid-libuuid-perl - uuid.h based UUID generation module libuuid-tiny-perl - pure Perl module to generate v1, v3, v4, and v5 UUIDs libuuidm-ocaml-dev - Universally unique identifiers for OCaml php-uuid - PHP UUID extension
>
> ~$ sudo apt-get install uuid-runtime
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done uuid-runtime is already the newest version (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.6). The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-43 linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.
>
> ~$ sudo apt-get install libuuid1
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done libuuid1 is already the newest version (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.6). The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-43 linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.
>
> ~$ sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done uuid-dev is already the newest version (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.6). The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-43 linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.

Following is the code in my test.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
int get_uuid();
int main()
{
  get_uuid();
  return 1;
}

int get_uuid()
{
  uuid_t uuid;
  uuid_generate(uuid);
  return 1;
}
```

> Error: /tmp/cchyLkZt.o: In function get_uuid':
>   test5.c:(.text+0x34): undefined reference touuid_generate' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Compilation Command -

```
cc -luuid test.c
```

Comment: As a quick check - does it work if you move `-luuid` *after* `test.c` in your compilation command? The linking order, in general, does matter.

Comment: No with or without -luuid it does not matter. Error remains the same

Comment: Stumbled upon the same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 and the UUID library. `gcc test.c -luuid` did the trick. Tested also with Ubuntu 16.04 container and the solution seems to apply to that. Clang does not care about the order of the parameters.